# Bind: non existing PTR record

Tags: bind, cache

Here is my bind `query.log`:

```
28-May-2012 13:34:00.370 queries: info: client IINTERNAL_DNS_IP#49428: view internal: query: 44.33.22.11.in-addr.arpa IN PTR + (EXTRENAL_DNS_IP)

28-May-2012 13:34:00.532 queries: info: client IINTERNAL_DNS_IP#50406: view internal: query: 44.33.22.11.in-addr.arpa IN PTR + (EXTRENAL_DNS_IP)

28-May-2012 13:34:00.697 queries: info: client IINTERNAL_DNS_IP#50674: view internal: query: 44.33.22.11.in-addr.arpa IN PTR + (EXTRENAL_DNS_IP)
```

I am receiving a lot for request from my Internal DNS Server: continuously ask for `11.22.33.44 PTR record`. `11.22.33.44 PTR record` does not exist, so it cant be cached.

Is any way to cache/block these requests and make extrenal DNS not to create a new query each time? Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Try to find, why the `11.22.33.44 PTR record` is asked rather than find a way to hinding logs.

Comment: 11.22.33.44 is a valid web application we have.

Comment: And do you have the DNS reverse delegation for this IP range ?

Comment: No. I am asking an other (authorative) DNS. The other DNS does not have a PTR record. The DNS admins of 11.22.33.44 told that they dont want a PTR.

Answer (score 0):

BIND should be caching the NXDOMAIN response. There's a whole [RFC dedicated to negative caching](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2308). There's a chance the far-end's zone SOA has the value set too low. [Read more on SOA settings](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch8/soa.html), particularly the last number ("min").

You *could* make a zone "44.33.22.11.in-addr.arpa" on your resolver and assign it data, if you can't get it working another way, but that's super-hacky.

Good luck!